# is not assignable to android.app.activity

Tags: android

My project has showing red highlighted text I need my project fixed
am not sure what has caused this to happen any suggestions.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="scrape2.myapplication" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="scrape2.myapplication.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity2Activity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2" >
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>



    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/parse_html"
            android:id="@+id/html_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="119dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:text="html"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_x="186dp"
            android:layout_y="1dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/parse_html"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="107dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/html_content" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="355dp"
            android:layout_height="421dp"
            android:layout_x="20dp"
            android:layout_y="118dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_x="264dp"
            android:layout_y="-1dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am not sure why its doing that please share me some tip thanks.

I tried to clean the project , also clicked the rebuild still no luck

activity class

```
package scrape2.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import static scrape2.myapplication.Constants.FIFTH_COLUMN;
import static scrape2.myapplication.Constants.FIRST_COLUMN;
import static scrape2.myapplication.Constants.FOURTH_COLUMN;
import static scrape2.myapplication.Constants.SECOND_COLUMN;
import static scrape2.myapplication.Constants.THIRD_COLUMN;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    public int count = 0;
    public String temp;
    private Document htmlDocument;
    private String htmlPageUrl = "http://en.masjidway.com/masjid/2804/prayer";
    private TextView parsedHtmlNode;
    private TextView textViewwww;
    private String htmlContentInStringFormat;
    private String dayys;
    private String amarrdatta;
    private String duhr_val1;
    private String asr_val1;
    private String maghreb_val1;
    private String isha_val1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        parsedHtmlNode = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.html_content);
        textViewwww = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2Activity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        Button htmlTitleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        htmlTitleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               JsoupAsyncTask jsoupAsyncTask = new JsoupAsyncTask();
                jsoupAsyncTask.execute();


            }
        });
 w(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
            String zuhrr =duhr_val1;//2
    w
```

Answer (score 1):

Your RelativeLayout doesn't belong in AndroidManifest.xml.  You should create a new xml file for every layout.

Comment: how do i go around fixing my mainactivity class or maybe layout? since the activity_main is the original layout already there

Comment: You can create a new layout file with RelativeLayout as the root element or just cut the whole RelativeLayout part and paste it inside the default main activity layout instead the default linear layout element.

Comment: i created new layout and cut and past this into main layout   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">     even pressed cleann no luck

Comment: Can you please post your activity class? Your class extends Activity?

Answer (score 1):

I think i have found a solution i have done many checks and for some reason the project plays up not sure why this is the test i have done at first

from relatetive layout changed only this name to linerlayout
then pressed 
clean project
rebuild
run project  then once it compiles the file opens the emulator or phone 
press cancle.
then close the  project and open it , it fixes it.

also you can just leave it as reletive layout and do the remaining steps it will fix it.

am not sure why it does that.